# ionicでjsのライブラリをnpmでインストールして使用する方法。

Tags: typescript, ionic2

ソーシャルシェアのライブラリ[jssocials](http://js-socials.com/start-using/)

を使おうとしております。

```
npm install jssocials
```

でインストールしたんですが、この後の使い方がわかりません。
jssocialsの使い方は、ドキュメントでは以下のようになってます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jssocials.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jssocials-theme-flat.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="share"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jssocials.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#share").jsSocials({
        shares: ["email", "twitter", "facebook", "googleplus", "linkedin", "pinterest", "stumbleupon", "whatsapp"]
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ionicだと、import文でモジュールを使用することになると思います。

```
import { メソッド名等 } from 'ライブラリ名'
```

が構文になると思いますが、上記のようなライブラリを使用する場合。
import文の`{}`内に何を記述したら良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ionic固有の話は分かりませんが、jssocialsはJavaScriptモジュールとして提供されているわけではないので、アンビエント宣言して使います。
追加でjqueryの型定義ファイルも必要なはずです。 `npm install @types/jquery`

次のようなjssocials.d.tsで最低限は使えると思います。

```
interface JsSocials {
    (arg: any): any;
}

interface JQuery {
    jsSocials: JsSocials;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！